# PyQt 5: QTableWidget display list values

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget

Esteemed there is a method which sets values ​​of the table element by element setItem (). Let's say I have a two-dimensional list, is there a way to quickly assign the values ​​of this list to a table without looping through them element by element?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: What does "quickly" mean? Why do you think looping isn't "quick"?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken in C#, this can be done in one line using one method.

Comment: Well, it seems quite trivial - why not just write your own method?